# Build Json string to tree view using jQuery and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am using asp.net and ajax to generate Json data.

When I am trying to draw tree using below code it's not working on other hand 
Code 2 section is working when I put it as static

Note: using library treant.js

link: [http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BikT.png)

Code 1:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Hello",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var Details = data.d;          
            if (Details != "")
            {
                var tree_design = '';
                //sessionStorage.setItem("str_data", tree_design);

                var currDepth = 0;
                var totalData = $.map(Details, function (n, i) { return i; }).length;
                var lastNodeIndex = parseInt(totalData) - 2;
                //-----------------------------------------//
                $.each(Details, function (index, item)
                {
                    if (Details[parseInt(index) + 1] === undefined || Details[parseInt(index) + 1] == null || Details[parseInt(index) + 1] == "") 
                    { 
                        //alert("undefined");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //console.log(index);

                        //console.log(item.Name);
                        //console.log(item.Depth);
                        //alert(item.Depth);
                        //console.log(item.Lft);
                        //-----------------------------------//
                        // Level down? (or the first)
                        if (((parseInt(item.Depth) > parseInt(currDepth)) || parseInt(index) == 0) && parseInt(item.Depth) != 0) {
                            tree_design += 'children: [';
                        }
                        //----------------------------------//
                        // Level up?
                        if (parseInt(item.Depth) < parseInt(currDepth)) {
                            tree_design += '' + '}],'.repeat(parseInt(currDepth) - parseInt(item.Depth));
                        }
                        //----------------------------------//
                        if (parseInt(item.Depth) != 0)
                        {
                            tree_design += '{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },';
                        }
                        //---------Print Node Text-------------//
                        tree_design += 'text: { name: "' + item.Name + '" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",';
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        //console.log(Details[parseInt(index) + 1].Depth);
                        var nextEleDepth = Details[parseInt(index) + 1].Depth;
                        //console.log(nextEleDepth);

                        // Check if there's chidren
                        if (parseInt(index) != lastNodeIndex && (parseInt(nextEleDepth) <= parseInt(item.Depth)))
                        {
                            tree_design += '},'; // If not, close the <li>
                        }
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        // Adjust current depth
                        currDepth = parseInt(item.Depth);
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        //console.log(parseInt(index)+"=="+lastNodeIndex);
                        // Are we finished?
                        if (parseInt(index) == lastNodeIndex) {
                            //console.log("Are we finished");
                            tree_design += '' + '}],'.repeat(currDepth);
                        }
                        //------------------------------------//
                    }
                });
                //------------------Draw Tree---------------------------//
                //console.log(tree_design);

                var chart_config = {
                    chart: {
                        container: "#basic-example",
                        nodeAlign: "BOTTOM",
                        connectors: {
                            type: "step"
                        },
                        node: {
                            HTMLclass: "nodeExample1"
                        }
                    },
                    nodeStructure: {
                        tree_design
                    }
                };

                //console.log(tree_design);

                new Treant(chart_config);
                //-------------------------------------------------------//
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Code 2: Working

```
     $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Hello",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var Details = data.d;          
            if (Details != "")
            {
                var tree_design = '';
                //sessionStorage.setItem("str_data", tree_design);

                var currDepth = 0;
                var totalData = $.map(Details, function (n, i) { return i; }).length;
                var lastNodeIndex = parseInt(totalData) - 2;
                //-----------------------------------------//
                $.each(Details, function (index, item)
                {
                    if (Details[parseInt(index) + 1] === undefined || Details[parseInt(index) + 1] == null || Details[parseInt(index) + 1] == "") 
                    { 
                        //alert("undefined");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //console.log(index);

                        //console.log(item.Name);
                        //console.log(item.Depth);
                        //alert(item.Depth);
                        //console.log(item.Lft);
                        //-----------------------------------//
                        // Level down? (or the first)
                        if (((parseInt(item.Depth) > parseInt(currDepth)) || parseInt(index) == 0) && parseInt(item.Depth) != 0) {
                            tree_design += 'children: [';
                        }
                        //----------------------------------//
                        // Level up?
                        if (parseInt(item.Depth) < parseInt(currDepth)) {
                            tree_design += '' + '}],'.repeat(parseInt(currDepth) - parseInt(item.Depth));
                        }
                        //----------------------------------//
                        if (parseInt(item.Depth) != 0)
                        {
                            tree_design += '{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },';
                        }
                        //---------Print Node Text-------------//
                        tree_design += 'text: { name: "' + item.Name + '" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",';
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        //console.log(Details[parseInt(index) + 1].Depth);
                        var nextEleDepth = Details[parseInt(index) + 1].Depth;
                        //console.log(nextEleDepth);

                        // Check if there's chidren
                        if (parseInt(index) != lastNodeIndex && (parseInt(nextEleDepth) <= parseInt(item.Depth)))
                        {
                            tree_design += '},'; // If not, close the <li>
                        }
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        // Adjust current depth
                        currDepth = parseInt(item.Depth);
                        //---------------------------------------//
                        //console.log(parseInt(index)+"=="+lastNodeIndex);
                        // Are we finished?
                        if (parseInt(index) == lastNodeIndex) {
                            //console.log("Are we finished");
                            tree_design += '' + '}],'.repeat(currDepth);
                        }
                        //------------------------------------//
                    }
                });
                //------------------Draw Tree---------------------------//
                //console.log(tree_design);

                var chart_config = {
                    chart: {
                        container: "#basic-example",
                        nodeAlign: "BOTTOM",
                        connectors: {
                            type: "step"
                        },
                        node: {
                            HTMLclass: "nodeExample1"
                        }
                    },
                    nodeStructure: {
                        text: { name: "BOD" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",children: [{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Kawser Hasan (Managing Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",},{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Md. Abdullah Al Baki (Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",}]
                    }
                };

                //console.log(tree_design);

                new Treant(chart_config);
                //-------------------------------------------------------//
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Code-3: Server Scripting (ASP.Net C#)

```
using CDB.System.Common.Layout.Company;
using PRP.PPL.System.include.config.connection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PPL.Data.HRD.Organogram.Tree1
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static Details[] Hello()
        {
            string sql;
            db_ppl Connstring = new db_ppl();
            sql = @"SELECT        node.category_id, node.name, COUNT(parent.category_id) - 1 AS depth, node.lft, node.rgt
                   FROM            nested_category AS node CROSS JOIN
                                            nested_category AS parent
                   WHERE        (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
                   GROUP BY node.category_id, node.name, node.lft, node.rgt
                    ORDER BY node.lft";
            List<Details> details_data = new List<Details>();

            using (SqlConnection con = Connstring.getcon)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Details col_data = new Details();
                        col_data.category_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        col_data.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                        col_data.Depth = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        col_data.Lft = reader.GetInt32(3);
                        col_data.Rgt = reader.GetInt32(4);                       
                        details_data.Add(col_data);
                    }
                }
            }

            return details_data.ToArray();
        }

        //---------------For Details Data----------------//
        public class Details
        {
            public Int32 category_id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Int32 Depth { get; set; }
            public Int32 Lft { get; set; }
            public Int32 Rgt { get; set; }           

        }
    }
}
```

Code-4: asp.Net Part

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CDB/System/Common/Layout/Master/Panel.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PPL.Data.HRD.Organogram.Tree1._default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    #basic-example
    {
        overflow: unset !important;
    }
</style>
<link href="../../../../../CDB/System/Assets/plugins/Organogram/Treant.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../../../../CDB/System/Assets/plugins/Organogram/basic-example.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../../../../../CDB/System/Assets/plugins/Organogram/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../CDB/System/Assets/plugins/Organogram/Treant.js"></script>

<script src="default.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">           
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- general form elements -->
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Book Progress</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="overflow:scroll;">
                                    <div class="chart" id="basic-example"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">

                        </div>                                                                                              
                    </div>                       
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Output :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tree_design='text: { name: "BOD" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",children: [{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Kawser Hasan (Managing Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",},{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Md. Abdullah Al Baki (Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",}]'; 



 nodeStructure: {                       
    tree_design
}
```

when you link tree_design in nodeStructure it's in string format but nodeStructure expect in json format 
either convert tree_design in json or do this way

```
var tree_design='{ name: "BOD" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",children: [{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Kawser Hasan (Managing Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",},{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Md. Abdullah Al Baki (Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",}]'; 

nodeStructure: {                       
    text: tree_design
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. please check my php  and asp.net code which is given below  code is working in php but i want to do it in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

I have solution in PHP code is given below now, I want to convert it to asp.net by using Ajax and jQuery

```
<?php
    include('../../connection/connection.php');
    error_reporting(0);

    //--------------Tree Design---------------//
    $sql_tree = "SELECT node.category_id,node.`name` AS Name, (COUNT( parent.`category_id` ) -1) AS depth,node.`lft`,node.`rgt`,
IFNULL((SELECT `category_id` 
           FROM `nested_category` t2 
           WHERE t2.lft < node.lft AND t2.rgt > node.rgt    
           ORDER BY t2.rgt-node.rgt ASC LIMIT 1 ),0) AS parent_id  
     FROM `nested_category` AS node
            CROSS JOIN `nested_category` AS parent
                WHERE node.`lft` BETWEEN parent.`lft`
                    AND parent.`rgt`
            GROUP BY node.`name`
            ORDER BY node.`lft`";

    $qry_tree = mysqli_query($con,$sql_tree);

    $array_parent_data = array();

    // Build array
    $tree = array();
    while($fetch_tree=$qry_tree->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tree[] = $fetch_tree;
    }

    // Bootstrap loop
    $tree_design        = '';
    $currDepth     = 0; 
    $lastNodeIndex = count($tree) - 1;
    $parent_id="";

    // Start the loop
    foreach ($tree as $index => $currNode) 
    {
        $lr_distance=$currNode['rgt']-$currNode['lft'];

        $sql_path_height="SELECT * FROM `tree_details` WHERE `tree_id`=".$currNode['category_id'];
        $qry_path_height = mysqli_query($con,$sql_path_height);
        $fetch_path_height=$qry_path_height->fetch_assoc();
        $path_height=$fetch_path_height['level_height'];
        $path_height=($path_height=="")?0:$path_height;
        $level_change=($path_height/10);

        //-----------------------------------//
        // Level down? (or the first)
        //if (($currNode['depth'] > $currDepth || $index == 0) && $currNode['depth']!=0) {
        if (($currNode['depth'] > $currDepth) && $currNode['depth']!=0) {
            $tree_design .= 'children: [';
        }

        // Level up?
        if ($currNode['depth'] < $currDepth) {
            $tree_design .= str_repeat(']},', $currDepth - $currNode['depth']);
        } 

        // Always open a node
        $t = ($index == 0) ? 1 : 2;

        if($currNode['depth']!=0)
        {
            $tree_design .= '{
                                connectors: {
                                    style: {
                                        stroke: "#000000"
                                    }
                            },';
        }
        //--------------For Leaf--------------//        
        if($path_height>0 && $lr_distance==1)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<$level_change;$i++)
            {
                $tree_design.='pseudo: true,
                    connectors: {
                        style: {
                            stroke: "#000000"
                        }
                    },
                    children: [
                    {'; 
            }   
        }
        //-----------For Parent---------------//
        if($path_height>0 && $lr_distance>1)
        //if($lr_distance>1)
        { 
            $sql_all_child="SELECT * FROM `nested_category` WHERE `lft`>".$currNode['lft']." AND `rgt`<".$currNode['rgt'];
            $qry_all_child = mysqli_query($con,$sql_all_child);
            $all_child_list="";
            while($fetch_all_child=$qry_all_child->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $all_child_list.= ",".$fetch_all_child['category_id'].",";
            }
            //$all_child_list = str_replace(",,",',',$all_child_list);

            $array_parent_data[]=$currNode['category_id']."#".$path_height."|".$all_child_list;
            $array_parent_data=array_reverse($array_parent_data);

            for($i=0;$i<$level_change;$i++)
            {
                $tree_design.='pseudo: true,
                    connectors: {
                        style: {
                            stroke: "#000000"
                        }
                    },
                    children: [
                    {'; 
            }   
        }
        //---------Print Node Text-------------//
        $tree_design .= 'text: { name: "'.trim($currNode['Name']).'" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",';
        //---------Close Leaf Brackets---------//
        if($path_height>0 && $lr_distance==1)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<$level_change;$i++)
            {
                $tree_design.='}]'; 
            }   
        }
        //---------Close Parent Brackets---------//
        foreach($array_parent_data as $key => $parent_data)
        {
            $tmp_parent=explode("#",$parent_data);
            $tmp_parent_id=$tmp_parent[0];
            //echo $tmp_parent_id."<<>>".$currNode['parent_id']."<br>";

            //if($tmp_parent_id==$currNode['parent_id'])
            {
                $array_parent_data[$key] = str_replace(",".$currNode['category_id'].",",'',$parent_data);
                $check_child_list=explode("|",$array_parent_data[$key]);
                $parent_details = explode("#",$check_child_list[0]);
                $close_parent_id = $parent_details[0];

                //if($close_parent_id==$currNode['parent_id'] && empty($check_child_list[1]))
                if(empty($check_child_list[1]))
                {
                    //echo $tmp_parent_id."<<>>".$currNode['parent_id']."<br>";

                    $close_parent_height = $parent_details[1];
                    $close_parent_height=($close_parent_height=="")?0:$close_parent_height;
                    $level_change_parent = $close_parent_height/10;

                    //echo $close_parent_id."|".$close_parent_height."<br>";

                    for($i=0;$i<$level_change_parent;$i++)
                    {
                        $tree_design.='}],';    
                    } 
                    unset($array_parent_data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        //print_r($array_parent_data);
        //---------------------------------------//

        // Check if there's chidren
        if ($index != $lastNodeIndex && $tree[$index + 1]['depth'] <= $tree[$index]['depth']) {
            $tree_design .= '},'; // If not, close the <li>
        }

        // Adjust current depth
        $currDepth = $currNode['depth'];

        // Are we finished?
        if ($index == $lastNodeIndex) {
            $tree_design .= '' . str_repeat('}],', $currDepth);
        }
    } //End Loop
//-----------------------------------------------------//
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title> Tree </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Treant.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="basic-example.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #basic-example
        {
            overflow: unset !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart" id="basic-example"></div>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="Treant.js?id=<?php echo rand(); ?>"></script>

    <!--<script src="basic-example.js"></script>-->

    <script>
        var chart_config = {
            chart: {
                container: "#basic-example",

                nodeAlign: "BOTTOM",

                connectors: {
                    type: "step"
                },
                node: {
                    HTMLclass: "nodeExample1"
                }
            },
            nodeStructure: {
                //---------------------------------------------//
                <?php echo $tree_design; ?>
                //text: { name: "BOD" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",children: [{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Kawser Hasan (Chairman)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",},{ connectors: { style: { stroke: "#000000" } },text: { name: "Engr. Md. Abdullah Al Baki (Managing Director)" },HTMLclass: "blue",image: "images/no_member.png",}],             
                //---------------------------------------------//
            }
        };

        new Treant( chart_config );


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```