# How to Convert JSON String into new JSON Object with other structure using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Json string can't read by javascript help me to convert it javascript Json object

```
{
  text: {
    name: "ROOT"
  },
  HTMLclass: "blue",
  image: "images/no_member.png",
  children: [
    {
      connectors: {
        style: {
          stroke: "#000000"
        }
      },
      text: {
        name: "SAYED"
      },
      HTMLclass: "blue",
      image: "images/no_member.png",

    },
    {
      connectors: {
        style: {
          stroke: "#000000"
        }
      },
      text: {
        name: "DIDAR"
      },
      HTMLclass: "blue",
      image: "images/no_member.png",

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to type this in so that JavaScript will recognize it as a valid object as shown in @C.Koo's answer or are you asking how to programmatically convert a string you have received into a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() may be answer, and you should envelop keys in "".
But JSON(JavaScript Object Notation) means "Notation like Javascript Object".
So think originally. Like following;

```
    var obj = {
        text: {
            name: "ROOT"
        },
        HTMLclass: "blue",
        image: "images/no_member.png",
        children: [
            {
                connectors: {
                    style: {
                        stroke: "#000000"
                    }
                },
                text: {
                    name: "SAYED"
                },
                HTMLclass: "blue",
                image: "images/no_member.png",

            },
            {
                connectors: {
                    style: {
                        stroke: "#000000"
                    }
                },
                text: {
                    name: "DIDAR"
                },
                HTMLclass: "blue",
                image: "images/no_member.png",

            }
        ]
    };
    console.log(obj);
```

Thank you.

Comment: please see my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205383/build-json-string-to-tree-view-using-jquery-and-asp-net   when i am generation json string in variable  when i am converting json object i got below error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Md. Didarul Islam, I'm sure that the first key(I mean `{key:value}`) is begun with `e`. When we use `JSON.parse()`, all keys must be enveloped in `""`. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score -1):

You want JSON.parse().

See [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for more details.